# Simulating Rotor Blades for Quadcopter

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, aerodynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I would like to simulate various shapes for rotor blades that will be used in a quadcopter. Which simulation software is used to understand how shapes, rotation interacts with the surrounding air? I know some physics, solving differential equations etc. I have AutoCad experience, and can work with Python APIs, Matlab, or compile, run any C, C++ based code. I am looking for something simple to use, where I can design a shape in a text file, or through CAD (another question which free CAD software to use), and import it somehow, and run it in a simulated aerodynamics environment so I can see how much lift there is, if defective failure, etc.

Words I've come across while searching is multibody dynamics, computational fluid dynamics (if air can be seen as lighter liquid). I read about Gazebo, does it allow designing elements from ground-up? Unreal physics engine sounds cumbersome to install and deal with. Any more suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Does OpenFOAM do stuff like that?

Comment: I also came across MBDyn, not sure of its visual simulation capabilities though..

Comment: I think the ones you mention look like rigid body physics simulators, not for airflow. I don't work with this but job ads usually list tons of software applicants should know...

Comment: You might be right; aerodynamics, if any, seem to be an add-in, an afterthought almost for these tools.

Comment: OpenFOAM for rotating rotors video - https://youtu.be/NlTsN4cAGaQ - this could be useful